# Changing a JavaScript graph

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get inspired by this code: 
https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/stackedArea.js
The output would be something like: http://nvd3.org/ghpages/stackedArea.html
My question is that how can I get rid of the radio buttons? Is it something that I should look for in the javascript libraries that I added? like:

```
<script src="data/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script src="data/nv.d3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set

```
showControls = false
```

or

```
.nv-controlsWrap  { display:none }
```